# Why is Android Virtual Device (AVD) so big

Tags: android-virtual-device

I'm running Windows 8.1 and currently use Eclipse Juno and all the latest SDK's.
About 2 months ago I was able to run emulators at normal (decent size) size.  Now, most (only 4.7" runs at good size if I set scale 0.5) emulators are way too big.  They go the hight of my screen and are very wide.  I don't know what happened from 2 months ago to today.  I've also gone to the Control Panel->Appearance & Personalization->Display and changed things there in hopes of making my AVD's run at normal size to no avail.

The funny thing is that while developing on Eclipse, I preview the layouts and they look fine until I run the emulator.  I need help and I'm asking if someone knows how to fix this issue?  Many thanks in advance.

JDP